# How to convert Go's []byte to C's *uint8_t

Tags: c, go, elf, cgo

I want to set a uint8_t* in a C struct using Go.
The data in Go comes from and ELF and is a byte slice.
This is the error I currently get:

`cannot use &buf[0] (type *byte) as type *_Ctype_uchar in assignment`

using this code:

`args.vm_snapshot_data = &buf[0]`

How do I do it?

When I use the proper cast:
`args.vm_snapshot_data = (*C.uint8_t)(&buf[0])`
I get this error:
`panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer`

Comment: The cgo type isn't `uint8_t`, it's `C.uchar`, so that's what you want to convert it to.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Passing a C.uchar is the same as passing a C.uint8_t

Comment: You're not converting it to either in this example, so it's hard to tell, and the error says `_Ctype_uchar`. Convert it to the type it says you need.

Comment: In the error message you can see it requires me to pass a C.uchar, but the field in C actually is a uint8_t. Cgo's conversion does this

Comment: That's fine, but you haven't tried converting it to either from what you've shown (make sure you are certain you want to pass a Go slice to C in the first place. It's much safer to copy the bytes into C allocated memory)

Comment: I tried all combinations. Updated my question and added a cast example

Comment: But can you show me an example that explains how to copy the bytes into C allocated memory?

Comment: See `C.CBytes` in the [`cgo` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golang count types rather than compatibility of them. And there's only one method to cast over the place it's using `unsafe.Pointer` as original value.

```golang
args.vm_snapshot_data = (*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0]))
```

If you’re not sure if buf slice will be alive on the Go side (garbage collector might dispose it) at the time when C side using it, then you have to use copy and dispose it manually.

```golang
args.vm_snapshot_data = (*C.uint8_t)(C.CBytes(buf))

...

C.free(unsafe.Pointer(args.vm_snapshot_data))
```